# On product import/cron my tax class field in admin is not being updated

Tags: admin, import, tax, array, tax-class

I have this method inside of:

```
parser/product.php
```

These fields are what i'm targeting in the admin panel. Everything updates properly, if a product gets imported with a different price matching the sku it updates. The only field that doesn't update is "Merch Tax Category Code which the field in the db is "tax_class_id". See screenshots of inspect element.[image]

```
protected function _getFieldNames()
{
    return array(
        'Company Number' => 'company_number',
        'UPC Code' => 'sku',
        'Product Code' => 'style_number',
        'Description' => 'name',
        'Size' => 'size',
        'Price' => 'price',
        'Merch Tax Category Code' => 'tax_class_id'
    );
}
```

Inside of my Adapter folder it contains (`Adapter/Product.php`):

```
protected $_attributesToUpdate = array(
    'name'           => 1,
    'description'    => 1,
    'company_number' => 0,
    'style_number'   => 0,
    'color'          => 0,
    'size'           => 0,
    'inseam'         => 0,
    'price'          => 1,
    'weight'         => 1,
    'tax_class_id'   => 1
);
```

Not all the fields matter but price and tax is important. Price already works so now i'm just configuring tax_class_id. I believe it's set to default on Taxable goods based on this code below.

Also in `Adapter/Product.php`:

```
protected function _getTaxClassId($importData)
{
    return '2'; //Taxable goods
}
```

The only other field that would identify anything to do with tax is also in the same file.

```
//Set Tax Class
if (empty($importData['tax_class_id'])) {
    $importData['tax_class_id'] = $this->_getTaxClassId($importData);
}

return $importData;
```

I've tried so many options so I'm now reaching out to you guys. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I've solved that annoying issue using this snippet of code, modifying directly the eav_attribute table:

```
 $taxAttr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
                 ->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'tax_class_id');
 Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
       // Set an array of product ids to update
       array($product->getId()),
       // Set an array with attribute ids and their value ids to update
       array($taxAttr->getId() => $your_tax_class_id),
       // Store Id
       0
 );
```